# PERL Dancer2, cgi dispatcher and uri_for helper

Tags: apache, perl, .htaccess, cgi, dancer

I have a web interface that i need to maintain and improve, written in a plain old CGI.pm way. That app is not using templating system neither. It's served by apache, like that:

```
/var/www/vhost/myapp/cgi-bin/app.cgi
              /htdocs/css/styles.css
              /htdocs/js/script.js
```

To add new pages to that app, and make my life easyer, i want to host a Dancer or Dancer2 app next to it, i was thinking about something like that:

```
/var/www/vhost/myapp/cgi-bin/app.cgi
                    /cgi-bin/dispatch.cgi (the one from Dancer2)
                    /htdocs/css/styles.css
                           /js/script.js
                           /dancer_public/...
                    /dancer2/lib/...
                            /views/...
                            /environement/...
```

In the dispatcher, i'm changing the path to reach the Dancer2 bin/app.psgi.
I added the following .htaccess file to the htdocs dir:

```
# BEGIN dancer application htaccess
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /v2
  RewriteRule ^/v2$ /cgi-bin/dispatch.cgi [L]
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule v2/(.*) /cgi-bin/dispatch.cgi/$1 [L]
# END dancer application htaccess
```

By doing that,

- accesssing to example.com/cgi-bin/app.cgi show me the old app
  as expected
- accesssing to example.com/v2 show me the dancer
  app home page, default one, without css, which is expected as i moved
  the public dir, and some other modification

Now that you have the setup, here is where i have an issue,
the redirection from v2 to the dancer app is working really well, however, in order to keep consistent, i would like to have the **uri_for** creating url from v2 , but it's using the SCRIPT_NAME as base url, to show the issue, when i'm creating that url: uri_for('/mypage'),

- i would like to have that url : example.com/v2/mypage,
- but instead i have url example.com/cgi-bin/dispatch.cgi/mypage

SCRIPT_NAME environment variable is containing cgi-bin/dispatch.cgi , i have one terrible hack, that is working, but clearly not the solution, i can have my expected behavior by forcing SCRIPT_NAME to /v2 in the cgi dispatcher, in a BEGIN block.
If someone as a clean solution for that, that would be of a great help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem with D1.

$ENV{SCRIPT_NAME} = '';

inside dispatch.fcgi helps me.