# Perl Dancer2 deployment, strange URI behavior

Tags: apache, perl, mod-rewrite, deployment, dancer2

I am using Perl Dancer2 for my project.
On my local development environment everything works fine, but on my production server it generates all the links with the dispatch.cgi script in the links.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<% request.base %>/css/style.css">
```

creates

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dance.mydomain.tld/dispatch.cgi/css/style.css">
```

Same with an image link in embedded CSS:

```
background: url(http://dance.mydomain.tld/dispatch.cgi/images/random2k22/filename_2022_a4_960x347.png) top center no-repeat;
```

When I use the example Rewrite code for Apache httpdocs mentioned on the official [Dancer2::Manual::Deployment](https://metacpan.org/dist/Dancer2/view/lib/Dancer2/Manual/Deployment.pod), the site doesn't work at all as it hops in a redirection loop.

```
Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
# Apache 2.2
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
# Apache 2.4
Require all granted

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dispatch.cgi$1 [QSA,L]
```

When I use the following it at least loads. But it takes quite long for the image to load (via the dispatcher?):

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dispatch.cgi$1 [QSA,L]
```

It's so frustrating.

What am I not understanding and/or doing wrong here?

Comment: See also [PERL Dancer2, cgi dispatcher and uri_for helper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29725465/2173773) and [Mixed content & uri_for function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71021520/2173773)

Comment: Thank you, Håkon.
This totally was the solution.